# ROS Service/Client Memory leak?

Tags: ros, memory, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

i'm pretty new to ROS and programming, and I hope someone can help me with this problem:

Everytime I use a service in one of my nodes, the memory usage of the service node and the client node start rising limitless. First I thought I had a bug in one of my nodes or in my custom service, but I tried a modified [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) and got the same problem.
I only commented the ROS_INFO out, made two constant ints and added a loop to the client.

Service:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "lidar_sim/AddTwoInts.h"

bool add(lidar_sim::AddTwoInts::Request  &req,
         lidar_sim::AddTwoInts::Response &res)
{
  res.sum = req.a + req.b;
 // ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b);
 // ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%ld]", (long int)res.sum);
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_ints_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", add);
  ROS_INFO("Ready to add two ints.");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "lidar_sim/AddTwoInts.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_ints_client");

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<lidar_sim::AddTwoInts>("add_two_ints");
  lidar_sim::AddTwoInts srv;
  srv.request.a = 1;
  srv.request.b = 2;
  ros::Rate loop_rate(20);
  while(ros::ok())
  {
  if (client.call(srv))
  {
    //ROS_INFO("Sum: %ld", (long int)srv.response.sum);
  }
  else
  {
    //ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service add_two_ints");
  }

    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
}
```

After an hour, client and service use, according to gnome-system-monitor, 800MB memory.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and ROS indigo.
Valgrind also doesn't show any memory leak.

**Thanks for any help!**

BTW: lidar_sim is just a package I use to test various nodes in.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199753/ros-service/client-memory-leak?/) by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 305 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-12-18**:
Does this problem occurr for client and subscriber? I noted your client does not call into spinOnce(); Maybe some cleaning up is done there??

**Comment by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on 2014-12-19**:
@Wolf: I thought spinOnce() is only for publisher/subscriber not service/client? I tested it, but it doesn't make any difference.
@gvdhoorn: Thank you! It seems that the persistent mode works! I'm just curious why the non persistent mode piles up memory usage and how to get rid of it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-19**:
I only asked about persistent mode to see if that would change the behaviour you're seeing. You might want to report this to the [roscpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues) issue tracker. However, without valgrind results backing you up, I expect you'll encounter some scepticism.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-12-24**:
@Dirk Thomas FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, there was a memory leak in roscpp's base Transport class for ROS Indigo. You can see a full explanation in the pull request to fix the issue (which has now been merged): https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/570

The short version is that the Linux function [getifaddrs()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) requires a freeifaddrs() call once the list of network interface structures are no longer needed. Since this issue is present inside roscpp's base class, Transport, every new connection loses a few Kb in memory. This means ROS Service servers then devour memory if left alive for long enough. Fortunately, the fix was a one-liner.

As for debugging ROS with Valgrind, if you attempt to run 
`valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes rosrun package_foo executable_bar`,
 you will not get useful memory stats. I believe this is due to `rosrun` spawning your  node in a separate process. To get around this, you can call your executable directly: 
(from the root of your catkin workspace) 
`valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./devel/lib/package_foo/executable_bar`
Alternatively, you could write your own [launchfile with Valgrind in the launch-prefix](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB).

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-26**:
This should probably be the accepted answer. My answer provides only a (not too nice) workaround.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If valgrind doesn't show anything, I'd be hesitant to believe there is a leak. Could you try making the service connection *persistant* and see if that changes anything? See [roscpp/Overview/Services - Persistent Connections](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Services#Persistent_Connections).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-27**:
Was this actually *the* answer? Was there a leak, or is the reported behaviour by-design?

**Comment by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on 2014-12-28**:
Maybe not *the* answer, but it solves my problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-28**:
Was it actually a problem? Linux aggressively caches everything it can, so even though gnome system monitor may be showing 800MB, that might actually be by-design.
Defaulting to persistent connections is not really a solution, as it might cause other issues. Especially on shaky network connections.